# How do I use tailwind with ktor

Tags: tailwind-css, ktor

I am developing a site using KTOR from JetBrains https://ktor.io/ with their DSL for building html
https://ktor.io/docs/html-dsl.html. But, having tried it seems unworkable because the HTML content is generated on demand from the DSL and not available  for preprocessing by tailwind.
Can someone help with this or confirm that tailwind does not work with KTOR?
Sorta sad, tailwind seemed a nice fit otherwise.

Comment: As I can see in https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation, Tailwind generates an output CSS file from an input CSS file. Could you please point me out to where I could find information about preprocessing HTML? Anyway, you can generate HTML using DSL and store it in a file to make it processable for external tools.

Comment: First, the information about processing HTML: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration includes this "Tailwind CSS works by scanning all of your HTML, JavaScript components, and any other template files for class names, then generating all of the corresponding CSS for those styles."

Comment: Second, preprocessing HTML is a reasonable suggestion but (1) entails more workflow than I want (2) these are dynamic pages so, in general, can't be robustly preprocessed.

Comment: if Tailwind works only with files then you can save HTML and any other static content in files and process them with Tailwind.